# passing object between two views (iOS SDK)

Tags: iphone, ios, object, view

What is the best way to pass an object between two views and how would I go about doing so?

Comment: Are the two views under the same viewController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using two view controllers then making `property` will be best way for you.

```
in .h file 

NSString *name;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;

and in .m 

@synthesize name;
```

for more how to use property look -
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW1

Comment: from which you want to pass an object to the another view controller. For example i have a string obj in class A and i want to pass it in B then i can make a property in B and set it from A.

Answer (score 0):

Use the properties declared in each controller.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have two view controllers, `ViewController1` and `ViewController2`. In both header files (`.h`), add an instance variable:

`CustomObject *myObjectToPass;`

and also

`@property (nonatomic, retain) CustomObject *myObjectToPass;`

If you are passing a BOOL, int or float, then do not retain it, for an NSString, use `copy` in place of `retain`, etc.

In the implementation file (`.m`), synthesize the variable:

`@synthesize myObjectToPass;`

Now you can get and set the object between viewControllers. The best way to do this depends on how they are related (e.g. in a navigationController or a tabBarContoller, etc). This should get you started, though.